# Get one row from the Grouped View in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem with running my query in the SQL server. In MYSQL it worked fine but had to switch to the SQL Server.

Error message when running select query:

> Column `dbo.regioomzet.regio` is invalid in the select list because of it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

[image: Image for reference]

Code looks like this:

```
USE aenc;
GO

CREATE VIEW RegioOmzet (
    regio
    ,omzet
    )
AS
SELECT so.region
    ,Sum(p.unit_price * soi.quantity) AS omzet
FROM sales_order so
JOIN sales_order_item soi ON so.id = soi.id
JOIN product p ON soi.prod_id = p.id
GROUP BY so.region;
GO
```

Here is the select query where all goes wrong in SQL Server.

```
SELECT ro.regio
    ,MAX(ro.omzet)
FROM dbo.regioomzet ro
```

Basically, every row has an int for that I want the max int from that view returned so 1 row.  But I get the aggregate function group error. I don't know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using aggregate functions, SQL Server requires that all columns in the `SELECT` list either be aggregated or be explicitly added to a `GROUP BY` clause. Earlier versions of MySQL do not require this, which makes for faster typing but can yield unexpected/unwanted results.

So you just need to add the explicit `GROUP BY` clause to your query.

```
select ro.regio, MAX(ro.omzet)
from dbo.regioomzet ro
group by ro.regio;
```

*EDIT:* I misunderstood the desired output. For just the largest `max(ro.omzet)` row:

```
select top (1)
  ro.regio, 
  MAX(ro.omzet)
from dbo.regioomzet ro
group by ro.regio
order by MAX(ro.omzet) desc;
```

The `TOP(n)` syntax is the SQL Server implementation of `LIMIT n`, which MySQL uses.

Comment: I've tried that before, but is it not possible to get only 1 row as output? For example the regio with the largest omzet (ro.omzet) therefore the max(ro.omzet)

Comment: @LeslieLauw, I misunderstood the desired output. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Aah now it works! Thanks! SQL server is so much different than MySql :) still have to get used to different syntax

Comment: There are plenty of folks here who can help you translate as you're getting used to it. :)